# How to prove a solution to Hamilton's equations on the tangent bundle is second order?

Tags: hamiltonian-mechanics

Let $Q$ be a manifold   Let $q^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in 1 .. n$ be a chart of $Q$.

The tangent bundle $TQ$ has a chart $q^\alpha, \dot{q}^\alpha$.   It has an almost-tangent structure:

$$
J = dq^\alpha \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha} \text{  is a (1,1) tensor on $TQ$}
\\
\Delta = \dot{q}^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha} \text{ is a vector field on $TQ$ }
$$
A vector field $X$ on $TQ$ is "second order" if $JX = \Delta$, ie if $X(q^\alpha) = \dot{q}^\alpha$.    A second order vector field on $TQ$ is the same thing as a second order ODE on $Q$.

Let $L : TQ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lagrangian.  The Euler-Lagrange equation is

$$ 
JX = \Delta \\
\mathscr{L}_X (dL \cdot J) = dL
$$

The cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ has a chart $q^\alpha, p_\alpha$, and a symplectic structure $\omega = dq^\alpha \wedge dp_\alpha$.

The Legendre transform gives a map $\tau : TQ \to T^*Q$ given by $p_\alpha = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha}$. This is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha \partial \dot{q}^\beta}$ is not singular.

Define $\Omega = -d(dL \cdot J) $ This 2-form is the pullback of the symplectic form on the cotangent bundle. $\Omega = \tau^*\omega$.   It will give a symplectic structure to $TQ$ if $\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha \partial \dot{q}^\beta}$ is not singular.

Define $H = \Delta(L) - L$.  The Euler-Lagrange equations can be rewritten as Hamilton's equations:

$$  JX = \Delta \\
\Omega(X, Y) = Y(H) \text{ for all $Y$}$$

Assume $\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \dot{q}^\alpha \partial \dot{q}^\beta}$ is not singular.

What I'm confused by is that this pair of equations is overdetermined.  $\Omega(X, Y) = Y(H)$ is enough to fully determine $X$, so it should be possible to prove $JX = \Delta$.  But I can't seem to figure out how.   Are additional assumptions necessary to prove this?

Comment: The amount of geometric formalism obscures somewhat might be the core of your confusion. Writing things out in canonical coordinates on $T^*Q$ reveals that half of the $\Omega(X,-) = dH$ system is equivalent to $JX=\Delta$ by a crucial property of the Legendre transform, namely its involutivity ($\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\left(p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}(\dot{q})\right)$).

Comment: Thank you!   That makes perfect sense.